# Finding postgres user password, that wasn't set up during installation

Tags: postgresql, fedora

I'm following steps from this site:
[PostgreSQL Fedora tutorial](https://developer.fedoraproject.org/tech/database/postgresql/about.html)

and despite not being asked to set up password for the postgres user at any point, postgres suddenly requires it:

```
[postgres@B8-64-F1-BE-62-20 ~]$ sudo systemctl restart postgresql

We trust you have received the usual lecture from the local System
Administrator. It usually boils down to these three things:

#1) Respect the privacy of others.
#2) Think before you type.
#3) With great power comes great responsibility.

[sudo] password for postgres:

Sorry, try again.
```

My user account password doesn't work, neither does leaving it blank or typing "postgres". I tried clean reinstall of postgres a few times, just in case I missed anything.

How do I find this password?

I thought maybe I don't need this password, because typing the command from above without "sudo" seems to work (it asks me for my user account password then), but then again, when I type `passwd` to actually set up the password, it asks me for my current password, and the fun starts all over again.

Comment: That's all about the Linux accounts and passwords, not about the Postgres database users or passwords.

Comment: Postgres on Linux does not ask for a password, because by default it's setup to only allow `peer` authentication for the superuser, i.e. you can only connect to the database as the `postgres` database user when you are the `postgres` **Linux** user.

Answer (score 1):

When I look at this:

```
[postgres@B8-64-F1-BE-62-20 ~]$ sudo systemctl restart postgresql
```

It looks like you're in the context of the postgres user.

So when that `sudo` command is hit, sudo is going to ask for the password for the postgres user (whether it has one or not, or possibly, because postgres user isn't in the sudoers list).

What I think you need to do is:

`exit`

That will "undo" the `sudo su - postgres` which I'm suspecting you've done earlier (because that's one of the commands in the page you linked).

Once you've done the `exit` it the prompt should return to starting with your normal username.

And then, when you do `sudo systemctl restart postgresql` it's going to prompt you for *your* password, and then do the thing.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! When I try this `sudo systemctl restart postgresql` with my normal username it seems to work as well, at least doesn't throw any error.
But then, how do I go about changing the password with `passwd`?

Comment: @MiCie  Why do you think you need to?  You already accomplished the restart, which is what you wanted to do..